# I'm new to Data analysis, I have to perform impact analysis for Refresh on table.Is it required to refresh the parent tables and child tables as well?

Tags: oracle11g, toad

The table has a set of child tables and parent tables. Also has grand children, so would the refresh impact those tables as well.

I need to perform 'data refresh' and it is for getting all production data synced up to dev for a specific table, where we made changes. It is for test data setup basically. We are looking at 'Append and Refresh' instead of 'Truncate and Refresh'.
Example - we have a table for emp_sched that has a parent table emp and set of child tables with emp provisions.
Here the emp_sched table has PK reference to two tables (emp and emp_change).

Comment: Your question is too broad. Can you provide a specific example of the tables and their relationships and constraints? What _kind_ of "refresh" are we talking about? A materialized view; SQL merge; truncate and reload from scratch? What are the actual business requirements of your application and/or organization? Without that level of detail there isn't much we here can do.

Comment: Updated the description above.

Comment: Only you can determine if syncing child tables is necessary, based on your logical model and business rules (my _guess_ is you would want to update all tables for logical consistency). Only you can determine the best method (there are many, many possible) of synchronization to use, based on your architecture, available DB options, and level of expertise. When you have a problem with a specific implementation, with an error message we can troubleshoot, then you will have a valid question for the dba.stackexchange.com forum. This forum is for questions related to code and app development.